# Send WM_SETTINGCHANGE message to refresh desktop

Tags: windows, refresh, desktop, autoit, user32

I managed to programmatically change my desktop background via this one-liner:

```
DllCall("user32.dll", "int", "SystemParametersInfo", "int", 20, "int", 0, "str", $CmdLine[1], "int", 0)
```

… by drag and drop of the desired wallpaper onto the compiled script.

I have another program that changes the desktop but for some reason fails to send the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message (I can see the key `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper` getting updated). How can I send this message to trigger a wallpaper refresh? Is `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` the correct message? Or is the first script the only way?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
DllCall("user32.dll", "lresult", "SendMessage", _
     "int", 0xffff, _
     "int", 0x001a, _
     "int", 0x0014, _
     "str", "HKCU\Control Panel")
```

`0xffff` is for broadcasting the message to every window, `0x001a` stands for `WM_SETTINGCHANGE`, `0x0014` is the code for `spi_setdeskwallpaper`. The taskbar in Windows 7 flickers but the wallpaper doesn't change.

If you solve my problem in C, C++ or Visual Basic I'll convert it to AutoIt myself (I just need the numerical codes of the called functions).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <SendMessage.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>

Dim $hWnd = WinGetHandle('[CLASS:Progman]')
_SendMessage($hWnd, $WM_COMMAND, 0x0001A220)
```

Should work. Let me know if it doesn't, so I can update this answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I see a little flickering near the tray in the taskbar, but the wallpaper doesn't change. Anyway, I found this [tiny utility](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/wprefresh.exe) (wprefresh.exe), which seems to do the trick. When I manually change `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper` and run wprefresh, the new wallpaper becomes visible. I don't know what message it sends, it just works tho. Nevertheless, thank you for your interest.